# how to generate html from servlet

Tags: servlets

I don't understand how servlet generate html. I have one html page and there i need to write my name and password and when i click button sign in it's generate servlet signServlet.mk. Then i need to create session where i keep the user name and need to create cookie with his name. I did this but now this servlet need to generate html page catalog.html. So i don't know what to do here, do i need to override doGet or not?

Tnx a lot!

This is first html page
 
                     Корисничко име

```
                <label> Лозинка  <input type="password" name="pass"></label>

                <br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `doGet()` or `doPost()` method depending upon the type of request. As you are sending user name and password, it is strongly recommended to use `POST` request (can be achieved by wrapping your `HTML` body in `<form method="POST"></form>` tag.

Once you are done with that, you can override `doPost()` method in your servlet. Also you need to do the required configurations.

Good examples of same are provided [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Form-Data.html) and [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-registration-form-in-servlet).

Comment: So all the code i need to write in doGet() or doPost i don't need to write another html page?

Comment: Yes. That is possible.
However, if you don't want to write the whole code in your method then, you can create another jsp and forward the request to that jsp.
If you do not have any business logic in your doget()/doPost() method then you can directly forward the request to result jsp.